# Haskell foldr results in type error while foldl doesn't

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, fold

I'm working through "Haskell Programming From First Principles". In the chapter on Folding Lists, exercise 5f,

when I evaluate

```
foldr const 'a' [1..5]
```

I get

> No instance for (Num Char) arising from the literal ‘1’

However, with

```
foldl const 'a' [1..5]
```

I get `'a'`.

I get that the folds are lazy, `foldr` doesn't traverse the spine and `foldl` does. But even looking at the definitions of foldr and foldl,

```
foldr f z []     = z 
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs) 

foldl f z []     = z                  
foldl f z (x:xs) = foldl f (f z x) xs
```

I can't figure out why it would have this type error. I'm guessing that the compiler is inferring type of `x` (`Num`) based on the type of `z` (`Char`), but I can't see where it draws the connection, since `const` or `f` doesn't require its two arguments to be the same type.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "looking at the definitions [...] I can't figure out why it would have this type error" - Don't look at the definitions when diagnosing a type error, look at the types!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok look at the type of `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`

Starting from the right you obviously must have `a` be some instance of `Num` and `Enum` (because you use `[1..5]`)

Next you pass in `'a'` so you have `b ~ Char`

Finally you have `const` for the function - and const is `const :: a -> b -> a` - note how you now must have `a ~ b` because you unify

```
a -> b -> b
a -> b -> a
        ^^^^^
```

but this of course would mean that `'a'` must be a value of an instance of `Num` which `Char` is not ... there is your error (it's complaining about the 1 because starting left instead it's the point where the the problem becomes obvious)

---

`foldl` on the other side has `foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`

so now you have again `a` some instance of `Num`, `b` must again be `Char` but now `const` just fits in (just switch `b` and `a` in the type of const)

Comment: Ah, right on. I gotta make it a habit to check type definitions first when there's a type error. Thanks!

Comment: yeah - that's 99% of what you need to know to get warm with Haskell: check the types ;)

Answer (score 1):

`foldl` and `foldr` invoke `f` with a different order of arguments. That is `foldr` calls `const x 'a'`, but `foldl` calls `const 'a' x`. The result of the latter is 'a', which is fine, but the result of the latter is `x`, which is wrong because `x` is an `Int` and the result is supposed to have the same type as the accumulator (`Char`).

Answer (score 1):

This is a typing problem. The type of `foldl` is

```
foldl :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

and `foldr` type is:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

When you apply `foldr` to `const` you get:

```
foldr const :: Foldable t => b -> t b -> b
```

Next, you supply `'a'` argument, you get

```
(foldr const 'a') :: Foldable t => t Char -> Char
```

So, when you pass `[1..5]` as an argument it will try to unify `t Char` with `(Enum a, Num a) => [a]`. Type `Char` is an instance of `Enum` class but not `Num` and it is the reason why you get this error message.

Comment: Checking types of partially-applied functions sounds like a handy debugging technique. I'll be sure to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the order of arguments in a `foldl` and `foldr` are different.  Use `flip const` instead:

```
> foldr (flip const) 'a' [1..5]
'a'
```