# How to use foldl with operator

Tags: haskell

I thought that two codes should run properly

```
foldr (:) [] [1..5]
foldl (:) [] [1..5]
```

But I get error use foldl:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
Expected type: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
Actual type: a -> [a] -> [a]
Relevant bindings include it :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:253:1)
In the first argument of ‘foldl’, namely ‘(:)’
In the expression: foldl (:) [] [1 .. 5]
```

Why foldl not run?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047841/haskell-foldr-results-in-type-error-while-foldl-doesnt?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type signatures for `foldl` and `foldr` are slightly different in the function argument (they have switched arguments):

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b

foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

For `foldl` to work you can use `flip` which swaps the arguments of a function:

```
flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

I.e. this should work:

```
foldl (flip (:)) [] [1..5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by its equations:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl op z [] = z
foldl op z (x:xs) = foldl op (op z x) xs
```

The big difference between `foldr` and `foldl` is how the operator `op` works: `foldl` is tail recursive and applies the operator from left to right in contrast to `foldr` which does the oppossite.

So, what you'd probably want is this:

```
foldl (\(currentFold, element) -> element:currentFold) [] [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Which could be beautified using `flip` (as @mschmidt points out)

Recall that from `foldr` equations:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr op z [] = z
foldr op z (x:xs) = op x (foldr op z xs)
```

it will be slightly different:

```
foldr (\(element, currentFold) -> element:currentFold) [] [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Which is the same as the one you posted:

```
foldr (:) [] [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to understand it, is:

```
foldr (:) [] [1..5]
```

means

```
1 : (2 : (3 : (4 : (5 : []))))
```

while

```
foldl (:) [] [1..5]
```

means

```
(((([] : 1) : 2) : 3) : 4) : 5
```

The latter makes no sense: is uses numbers as if they were lists. Further, every usage of `:` changes the type of the output (`[]` is a list, `[]:x` is a list-of-lists, `([]:x):y` is a list-of-lists-of-lists, and so on).